# Convert native buffer to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, c++-cli, memorystream

In my C++\CLI i have this piece of code:

```
array<Byte>^ out_buf = gcnew array<Byte>(stream_size);
Marshal::Copy(IntPtr(buf), out_buf, 0, Int32(stream_size)); 
System::IO::MemoryStream^ stream = gcnew MemoryStream(out_buf);
```

in `MemoryStream(out_buf)`, does memory stream allocate memory again or just take ownership of the `out_buf`?

if `MemoryStream` does allocate memory again, is there way to convert native buffer to `MemoryStream`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you to treat `out_buf` (i.e., it does not allocate a new buffer) as a stream, so you have nothing to worry about another buffer being allocated.

Answer (score 2):

MemoryStream(out_buf) does not allocate memory, nor does it take ownership. The GC will clean it up.